# Array of items or multiple parameters typing in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have this function which takes an array of objects, or multiple objects passed as arguments:

```js
function mergeObjects(...sources){
  const src = Array.isArray(sources[0]) ? sources[0] : sources
  // ... do thing with src
}
```

I want to type this using typescript,

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
function mergeObjects(...sources: object[]){
  const src = Array.isArray(sources[0]) ? sources[0] : sources
  // ... do thing with src
}
```

How to declare that this is an array of objects, or multiple objects?

The function will be invokes using one of the following ways:

1. `mergeObjects({}, {}, {})`
2. `mergeObjects([{}, {}, {}])`

Comment: `{}` is an object in TypeScript so an array of objects would be `{}[]`

Comment: @nate-kumar, ok I know

Comment: TS doesn't really have a "non-array object" type to prohibit a call like `mergeObjects([{}],[{}])`, but you could approximate it like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WJArDm) shows.  Does that meet your needs or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by using function overloads. Here is an example

```js
function mergeObjects(sources: object[]): object
function mergeObjects(...sources: object[]): object
function mergeObjects(...sources: object[]): object {
  const src = Array.isArray(sources[0]) ? sources[0] : sources
  src // any[]
  // ... do thing with src

  return {}
}
```

Now both parameters are typed, but we still get src as any[] due to Array.isArray typeguarding its argument as `any[]`. This can also be fixed by adding another type guard on top of `isArray`

```js
function smarterIsArray<T>(arg: any): arg is Array<T> {
  return Array.isArray(arg)
}

function mergeObjects2(sources: object[]): object
function mergeObjects2(...sources: object[]): object
function mergeObjects2(...sources: object[]): object {
  const src = smarterIsArray<object>(sources[0]) ? sources[0] : sources
  src // object[]
  // ... do thing with src

  return {}
}
```